# How to generate unique ID for a table with 6 long characters instead of going from number 1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement a unique ID for every client. But the client number gets generated automatically which is also incremental in the database. But Instead of it starts from 1 I would like to start from 100000. So first entry in the table should take the id of 100000 and second entry should take 100001 and so on. how could I manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating the table using

```
MyColumn INT IDENTITY(100000,1)
```

will do the trick. If the table is already created, then

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 99999)
```

will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Identity Seed property to 100000 of column you want to start from 100000

Right click the table in SQL server object explorer and click Design

[image: Table properties]

Take properties of column whoes Identity Seed you want to change.

[image: Identity Seed]

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT=100000

Comment: DBCC CHECKIDENT ("dbo.myTable", RESEED, 100000); pls check this